# Node.js keeps a copy of a global variable inside local scope

Tags: node.js, node-request

I have a Node.js application that uses the request library to GET a number of URLs. The code is something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){

        var URL = docs[i].url;

        request(URL, function(error, response, html){
            console.log(URL);
            // Other code...
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, let’s say `docs` contain URLs like [URL1, URL2, URL3, ...]. With the first iteration, URL = URL1 and a request is sent to that URL. With the second iteration, a request is sent to URL2 and so on. However, at the end of the loop, URL = URLn. Inside the event complete function, when I log URL, I always get URLn. However, I need to able to get the respective URLs that is [URL1, URL2, URL3, ...].

Any idea, how I can maintain a local copy of the URL, that remains unchanged event when the global URL gets changed?

<sub>This must be something easy, but I can't figure it out.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the code in a function or use forEach. This happens because of closure scope.

```
docs.forEach(functiom(doc) {
    var URL = doc.url;

    request(URL, function(error, response, html){
         console.log(URL);
         // Other code...
    })
});
```

Another fix

```
for(var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){
    makeRequest(docs[i]);
}

function makeRequest(doc) {
    var URL = doc.url;

    request(URL, function(error, response, html){
        console.log(URL);
    });
}
```

And another a bit more uglier fix with a closure inside the for loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){
    (function(doc) {
        var URL = doc.url;

        request(URL, function(error, response, html){
            console.log(URL);
            // Other code...
        });
    })(docs[i]);
}
```

If you use something like [JSHint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSHint), it will warn you not to create functions inside *for* loops as it will cause problems like this.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it would be something easy!

Comment: I don't understand why would someone downvote this answer, and also downvote my question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you experience is normal behavior in JavaScript and no special behavior of Node.js.

The only thing in JavaScript that defines a scope are functions, and functions can access their own scope as well as any "outer" scopes.

Hence, the solution is to wrap your code in a function that takes the global variable as a parameter and provides it to the code within the function as a parameter: This one is evaluated for each call of the function, hence your inner code will get its own "copy".

Basically you have two options. Either use an *immediate executed function expression*. This is basically nothing but a name-less (i.e. anonymous) function that is called immediately where it is defined:

```
for(var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){
  (function (url) {
    request(url, function(error, response, html){
      console.log(url); 
    });
  })(doc.url);
}
```

Or use the built-in `forEach` function of an array which automatically wraps its body in a function (which results in the same effect):

```
docs.forEach(function (url) {
  request(url, function(error, response, html){
    console.log(url); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read about closures in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Meanwhile, in simpler terms, the value of `i` would reach `n` at the end of all iterations. Hence rightly you would get URLn every time. If you wrap the request inside a immediately invoked function expression, you are creating another level in the scope chain. By doing so, the callback to request method won't refer to the variable `i` in global scope, but to the variable `i` that was available in the scope of the function at the time of sending the request. And that value of `i` you expect.

Code would be something like this then:

```
for(var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){
    var URL = docs[i].url;

    (function(currentURL) {
        //now the URL is preserved as currentURL inside the scope of the function
        request(currentURL, function(error, response, html){
            console.log(currentURL);
            // This value of currentURL is the one that was available in the scope chain
            // Other code...
        });
    })(URL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `let` instead of `var`, i.e.:

```
for(let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){

        let URL = docs[i].url;

        request(URL, function(error, response, html){
            console.log(URL);
            //other code...
}
```

Comment: *Why* does that make a difference?